# Background на Canvas unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

В юнити есть Canvas с режимом Overlay. Он идеален для того чтобы сделать, например, загрузочный экран, когда изображение выводится поверх всего. Но как сделать с его помощью задний фон, который не будет меняться? UI перекрывает все и сортировать это я могу только относительно других UI элементов, относительно простых gameObject-ов изображение всегда на переднем плане. Как убрать изображения с Canvas на задний план, чтобы обычные GameObject отображались спереди него? Именно в режиме Overlay это как нибудь возможно?

Comment: Никак, Canvas - это UI, а UI для заднего фона не предназначен. Наверняка есть способы это сделать, но зачем?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker
Хорошо, но тогда как сделать корректно задний план, который не будет меняться вообще никак, несмотря на движение камеры? Только второй камерой? Хотелось обойтись без этого.

Comment: В скрипте двигаете задний в план в зависимости от положения камеры - все, что за способ с 2мя камерами мне даже страшно представить.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, если интересно, то примерно так: одна камера всегда смотрит на что-то и не двигается, вторая рисует после неё без предварительной очистки. Получаем все, что видит вторая камера, но нарисованное поверх того, что видит первая

Comment: @M.Green, а какой в этом смысл? Ну вариант рабочий да, но слишком костыльно для такой простой задачи?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, ну, я просто описал способ, о котором он говорил) а не предложил так делать.